# Accessing shadowed variables from inner scope

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

My code :

```
int num = 1; // global scope
int main(){
      int num = 2;                         // local scope 1
           {                              // local scope 2
             int num = 3;
              {                          // local scope 3
                  int num = 4;
                   std::cout<<num<<"\n";            // printing local scope 3
                   std::cout<<::num<<"\n";         // printing global scop 
                   // but here how to print local scope 1, 2 variables
               }
           }
```

Guys in my code there are nested scopes and I want to print all variables with same name, including shadowed ones, from "local scope 3". However, I can print global and local scope 3's num's value but I don't know the syntax for accessing the local scopes 1 and 2's num's value.

Comment: This is simply not possible, as you shadowing the scope1, 2 `num`s, and they can not be qualified by any namesapces. You need to rename them to get in the scope 3.

Comment: Why don't you just push these variables onto a stack and manage the stack automatically within each scope?

Comment: Having the same name for variables that results in variable shadowing is generally a bad idea because it decreases readability and maintainability. Having that indicates, that you should either change the naming scheme, or to split the function.

Comment: Use a recursive function and have each function print num as it unwinds?

Comment: What scope do you want to access at what point?  And can you give a better example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot just simply achieve this as the inner variable just overshadows your outer scope variable.

If an inner block declares a variable with the same name as the variable declared by the outer block, then the visibility of the outer block variable ends at the point of the declaration by inner block.

However, if you still need to achieve this, you can do something to store the variable values in a stack that saves the variable values per scope. This is something similar to what is done during function calls (just a revised version to store only variable you require).

I would still suggest you to instead use a separate name for variables as this reduces readability of code.

Answer (score 1):

just use in your scope:

```
int num = 1; // global scope

int main() {

    int num = 2;                        
    {                             
        int num = 3;
        {                          
            int num = 4;
            std::cout << num << '\n';                       
           
        }
        std::cout << num << '\n';          
    }
    std::cout << num << '\n' << ::num;          
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the user [jasmeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8652760/jasmeet) pointed out, you simply cannot do that directly. However, indirectly there is a workaround to this but it would call for the use of a container...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int num = 1;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> results;
    results.push_back(num);
    int num = 2;
    results.push_back(num);
    {
        int num = 3;
        results.push_back(num);
        {
            int num = 4;
            results.push_back(num);
            for (auto& v : results)
                std::cout << v << " ";
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want exactly.  You use the word recursion, but you
are not using recursion.

However, I think what you are describing and want would suit a recursive function.
Maybe something like the following do what you want?

```
#include <iostream>

void printnum(int num, int max)
{
    if (num < max)
        printnum(num+1, max);
    
    std::cout<<num<<"\n";
}
    
int main(){
  printnum(1, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, what about this ( don't do that in production code ), lambdas can be declared without `()` be called thru `operator ()` and never assigned:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {  

    int num = 10;
    [num_ = num] {
      int num = 11;
      std::cout << "num " << num << "\n";
      std::cout << "outer_num " << num_ << "\n";
    }(); 

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jbhYTf

Answer (score -1):

Probably it is something like a hacker task.
I've spent some time dealing with pointers, etc. And got some solution:

```
#include <iostream>

int num = 0;
int main()
{
    int *addressNumGlobal = &num;
   std::cout << "Address num global: " << addressNumGlobal << endl; 
   int num = 1;
   int *addressNum1 = &num;
    std::cout << "Address of num 1: " << addressNum1 << std::endl;
   {
       int num = 2;
       int *addressNum2 = &num;
       std::cout << "Address of num 2: " << addressNum2 << std::endl;
       {
           int num = 3;
           int *addressNum3 = &num;
            std::cout << "Address of num 3: " << addressNum3 << std::endl;
           char *myNum = (char*)(&num);
           int *addressNum2 = (int*)(myNum + sizeof(int));
            std::cout << "Calculated Address of num 2: " << addressNum2 << std::endl;
           int num2Value = *addressNum2;
           std::cout << num2Value << std::endl;
           std::cout << ::num << std::endl;
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting the following output:

```
Address num global: 0x601174
Address of num 1: 0x7ffc8db08b68
Address of num 2: 0x7ffc8db08b64
Address of num 3: 0x7ffc8db08b60
Calculated Address of num 2: 0x7ffc8db08b64
2
0
```

Of course, the addresses are changing from run to run but the access to num(2) is obtained:)

So num(1), num(2), num(3) are stored in a "row". And probably it will fail on a different compiler. But anyway it is a nice stuff to think of:)